# How to create/mutation entity with sub relation on apiplatform/graphql

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, graphql, api-platform.com

I want to create two entities that are related. How can I create the first entity with the required sub-entity.

I've tried the following code but graphql returns the following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$stock\" of type \"createProductInput!\" used in position expecting type \"String\".",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "graphql"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 7,
          "column": 3
        },
        {
          "line": 15,
          "column": 17
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The mutation:

```
mutation createProduct ($input: createProductInput!) {
  createProduct(input: $input) {
    clientMutationId

    product {
      uuid
      name
      sku
    }
  }
}
```

the variables:

```
{
  "input": {
    "name": "ProductAAA",
    "sku": "product_aaa",
    "stock": {
      "quantity": 33,
      "unit": "s"
    }
  }
}
```

Oddly the createProductInput says that stock is a string instead of an object.

```
uuid: String!
name: String!
sku: String!
stock: String
clientMutationId: String
```

These are my entities:

```php
// Product.php

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource
 * @ApiFilter(ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter::class, properties={"name": "partial", "sku": "partial"})
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="uuid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
     *
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $sku;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Stock", cascade={"PERSIST"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="stock_id", referencedColumnName="stock_id")
     *
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $stock;
}
```

```php
// Stock.php

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="stocks")
 */
class Stock
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="stock_id", type="uuid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
     *
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $unit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a nested entity in a mutation, you need to create the nested entity first then use its IRI in the mutation.
That's why the type is *String*.

It was possible before but has been removed because it was causing some issues.
See: https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1886

Comment: Bummer! Is it then possible to create entityA and get the IRI as a variable to use in entityB's mutation? Or do I have to make two separate mutation calls? Which sucks.

Comment: You have to make two mutation calls, sorry for that. There is an RFC going on to add the input union type: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/blob/master/rfcs/InputUnion.md Another solution would be to have two fields (one for the IRI, the other for data) but it needs work.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Will use two mutation calls for the time being.

Comment: What about creating a custom mutation? And in the resolver - u can inject the EntityManagerInterface so u can create entities like in a normal symfony controller and persist it...

Comment: @AlanPoulain can you share some more insights about **how** to do that? How should that "IRI" look like?

Comment: Yeah, but how do I do multiple mutations with React Relay, where we have one mutation per component?

Answer (score -1):

```
mutation CreateUser{
  createUser(input: {
    email: "user@test.com", 
    username: "user@test.com", 
    role: "ROLE_USER",
    password: "bonjour",
    enabled: true,
  }) {
    user{
        id
      email
      username
      role
      reference
      enabled
      created
      updated
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your example shows the creation of a single entity. This issue is about creating a sub-entity.